# Keyless NSDictionary from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create JSON that would look like

```
[
   {
      property1 = "test1",
      property2 = "test2",
   },
   {
      property1 = "test1",
      property2 = "test2",
   },
   ...
]
```

So far all I can get using NSDictionary is this:

```
[
   key1 = {
      property1 = "test1",
      property2 = "test2",
   },
   key 2 = {
      property1 = "test1",
      property2 = "test2",
   },
   ...
]
```

... which is no good. Is there an easy way creating keyless array inside NSDictionary?

Comment: What type is that ? What JSON encoder are you using ? Can you show us deserialization code + NSLog type of what you are getting out of JSON

Comment: show me your code for creating this JSON

Comment: A "keyless dictionary" is nothing more than an `NSSet`...it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
NSArray *objects = @[
    @{ @"property1": @"test1", @"property2": @"test2" },
    @{ @"property1": @"test1", @"property2": @"test2" }
];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:objects options:0 error:&error];
```

Looks like you were using a `NSDictionary` as the root object, instead of an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid. Either it should be a JSON array like this:

```
[
   {
      property1 : "test1",
      property2 : "test2",
   },
   {
      property1 : "test1",
      property2 : "test2",
   },
   ...
]
```

or a JSON object with other objects embedded, although in this case, you would need to specify the properties' names:

```
{
   obj1 : {
      property1 : "test1",
      property2 : "test2",
   },
   obj2 : {
      property1 : "test1",
      property2 : "test2",
   },
   ...
}
```

The first case maps to an NSArray of NSDictionaries, while the second maps to an NSDictionary with tow keys (obj1, obj2,), each mapping to an NSDictionary with two keys each (property1, property2).

Judging by the edits made to your question, you need to serialize this object, to get the desired structure:

```
NSArray * dataForJSON = @[
    @{
         @"property1" : @"test1", 
         @"property2" : @"test2"
     },        
    @{
         @"property1" : @"test1", 
         @"property2" : @"test2"
     }
];
```